# Grammar explanation for と粘ってよかった

Tags: grammar, keigo, sonkeigo

I'm trying to translate a conversation where one person compliments another person, and they replied with:

そうおっしゃっていただける**と粘ってよかった**と思います！ありがとうございます！

粘る (ねばる) - "to persist"

I think it roughly translates to "because you say so, I'm glad! Thank you!" but I'm confused about the と粘って part. Who is it referring to? 
Does it mean:

"Because you say so, I'm glad **I persisted**"?

microsoft had translated it as: "I'm glad that **you persist** to say so"

But if it were this case, why is it と粘って? Shouldn't it come before the verb and also use the honorific keigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It literally means "If you (kindly) say so, I think it was good that I persisted." You can forget what Microsoft said.

そう言って頂けると is "If you say so" (this と is not quotative-*to* but [conditional-*to*](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals#Expressing_natural_consequence_using)). This 粘る ("to persist", "to hold on", "not to give up") refers to what this person did (during the match, etc.)

Comment: I was not aware it was the conditional-to! Thanks for your help!